# Conversão da função EnCrypta de Delphi para JavaScript

Tags: javascript, delphi

estou com um problema para converter essa função,
gostaria que alguém me ajudasse

**Codigo em Delphi**

```
function EnCripta(const InString:string; StartKey,MultKey,AddKey:Integer): string;
var I : Byte;
  begin
  Result := '';
  for I := 1 to Length(InString) do
  begin
    Result := Result + CHAR(Byte(InString[I]) xor (StartKey shr 8));
    StartKey := (Byte(Result[I]) + StartKey) * MultKey + AddKey;
  end;
end;
```

**Codigo em JavaScrypt**

```
var EnCripta = function (inString, startKey, multKey, addKey) {
            var I;
            var result = "";
            var vStartKey = startKey;
            for (I = 0; I < inString.length; I++) {
                var codigo = inString.charCodeAt(I) ^ (startKey >> 8);
                codigo = codigo & 0xff;
                var a = String.fromCharCode(codigo);
                result = result.toString( 'ASCII' ) + a;
                startKey = ((result.charCodeAt(I) + startKey) * multKey + addKey);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Algumas palavras ate que funciona, mais outras não

Por Favor caso tenha alguém
me ajude

Comment: Seu problema é no encoding. Agora basta saber em qual das linguagens. Passando a string `blablabla`, o Delphi retorna `bnm]Ĭإἴ鳜༔` e o javascript retorna `bnm],%4Ü`

Comment: No meu caso esta sendo no javascript, pois estou tentando acessar uma senha salva pelo delphi

Comment: como posso resolver?

Comment: Verificando mais um pouco cheguei no banco de dados, estou utilizando o Firebird, com o node-firebird